# Auto Naming In Oracle DataBase when inserting to table

Tags: oracle, auto-increment

I have two table: table_1 and table_2.
In these tables there are two columns: p_code (varchar2) and o_code (varchar2) and both of them primary key. So we have:

```
table_1.p_code,
table_1.o_code,
table_2.p_code,
table_2.o_code
```

I want to copy table_2 into table_1 but there may be some same rows that already exist in table_1. I thought i could handle this situation with function or procedure but i couldnt. How can i handle this?

By the way: Two Example table and columns:

```
Table_1:
P_code    O_code
C123      PREP100
C123      PREP101

Table_2:
P_code    O_code
C123      PREP101
C123      PREP102
```

I want to insert table_2 into Table_1 but C123 PREP already exist in Table_1. I thought i could sperate the last three char, trun into number, increase one, turn into varchar2, and see if exist in table_1. But i couldnt write the sql procedure or function for it...

Comment: I thought i can handle the situation with increasing last char of O_code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like:

```
insert into table_1 (p_code, o_code)
(-- add all rows in table_2 that are not present in table_1
 (select t2.p_code, t2.o_code from table_2 t2 
 minus
 select t1.p_code, t1.o_code from table_1 t1)
 union all
 -- add all rows in table_2 that are present in table_1
 (select t2.p_code, t2.o_code || '_2' from table_2 t2
  join table_1 t1a on t2.p_code = t1a.p_code and t2.o_code = t1a.o_code)
);
```

This will insert the new rows unchanged and suffix the existing rows with _2; you could then easily run an UPDATE statement afterwards to generate unique Ids, or (preferably) use a sequence to generate the new IDs in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

This should work in most SQL engines ([SQLFiddle Demo for Oracle 11G](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9fc19/1)):

```
INSERT INTO table_1 (p_code, o_code)
SELECT p_code, o_code FROM table_2
MINUS
SELECT p_code, o_code FROM table_1
```

By your example I assume that your primary key is `(p_code, o_code)`.

**UPDATE**: SQL92 has standard `EXCEPT` operator, but Oracle does not support it. Instead, it uses `MINUS`, which works exactly the same.

Comment: I want to insert table_2's first row: (C123 - PREP101) as (C123 - PREP103).

Comment: I dont want to lose the table_2's first row, minus lose the row. i want to rename it

Comment: Ah, it was not clear from your question. In that case, you are better off writing some script to do that for you, like Perl or Python. Oracle's only supports numeric sequences, not character based